# How to generate a one hot encoder?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to apply a OneHotEncoder to a column from a dataframe named "year". I tried seperating this column from the dataframe and then running it in the function but keep on getting the error message:

```
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

The code is:

```
import sklearn
year = articles["year"]

year2 = sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(year)
```

I hoped that the function would work, or at least not give this error message.

Comment: The OneHotEncoder constructor only accepts keyword arguments. See: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you should give the argument to fit function:

```
sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder(drop='first').fit(year)
```